# How can i call a javascript function using php code with php variable passing

Tags: php, javascript

This is my php code:

```
<?php
  $typeid = 65;
  $subledgerid = 'subledger'.$typeid;
  $loadledger = 'loadledgers';
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">view_subledger('<?php echo $subledgerid;?>',<?php echo $typeid;?>,'<?php echo $loadledger;?>');</script>
```

This is not calling the `view_subledger()`.

But when i call something like this it will work fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">view_subledger('subledger65',65,'loadledgers');</script>
```

How can i call this?

Comment: show us the output result(page source code).
check line 7 :   <?php } ?>

Comment: Is `$subledgerid;` numeric? Than you are missing the prefix `subledger`. Anyhow, post us the HTML output that you have when you are doing stuf with PHP.

Comment: The last line has a closing brace that doesn't match up. What is above this code in the file?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk `$subledgerid` is alphanumeric....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the safest way to do this:

```
<?php

$typeid = 65;
$subledgerid = 'subledger'.$typeid;
$loadledger = 'loadledgers';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
view_subledger.apply(window, <?php print json_encode(array(
  $typeid,
  $subledgerid,
  $loadledger
)); ?>);
</script>
```

Which generates following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
view_subledger.apply(window, [65,"subledger65","loadledgers"]);
</script>
```

json_encode() will ensure that variables are escaped properly and with .apply() method you can pass parameter array to JS function.

Another suggested version:

```
<?php
$typeid = 65;
$subledgerid = 'subledger'.$typeid;
$loadledger = 'loadledgers';
$param_str = implode(', ', array_map('json_encode', array(
  $typeid,
  $subledgerid,
  $loadledger
)));
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
view_subledger(<?php print $param_str; ?>);
</script>
```

Generates following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
view_subledger(65, "subledger65", "loadledgers");
</script>
```

Comment: `window` should be the passed `this` object.

Comment: I also suggest changing the method signature to `view_subledger(data)` in this case.

Comment: 1) author of the question can change function signature i think; 2) yes json_encode() can be used for any - non array or non object values too.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `<?php } ?>` after the script? Should be like:

```
<?php
$typeid = 65;
$subledgerid = 'subledger'.$typeid;
$loadledger = 'loadledgers';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">view_subledger('<?php echo $subledgerid;?>',<?php echo $typeid;?>,'<?php echo $loadledger;?>');</script>
```

Comment: Probably a copy-paste issue

Answer (score 0):

This is all the code you have in the file?
All this looks OK and must work as far as $subledgerid, $typeid,$loadledger are correct.
But what about this line?

```
  <?php } ?>
```

It must crash the script

Comment: Probably a copy-paste issue